# PowerShell: Default column width for all objects

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-5.0

Currently, in PowerShell 5, when outputting tables, the default padding between columns is only 1 character space; which doesn't make default output for items in tables very readable.  I didn't used to have this problem in PowerShell 2.

I am looking a way to change the **default** padding/column size for **ALL** tables in PowerShell (without having to use a custom format table command for every single command I do that returns a table).  Also, using a custom format-table ruins the command so it can't be piped into another command.

Hopefully, someone knows of a clever way to do this.

Comment: *Also, using a custom format-table ruins the command so it can't be piped into another command.* - brilliant. `Format-Table` followed by a pipe character should be a parse error in PowerShell. It's like "I printed this spreadsheet to a PDF, now how do I get the data back out to open it in Excel again?"

Answer (score 0):

You can try to define your own custom view and work via:

```
|format-custom –view MyView
```

This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714665.aspx#defineobjectformatting) gives additional information about custom views. You can check the predefined views located under `$PSHOME\*.format.ps1xml`. You can also check [about_format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_format.ps1xml).

Hope that helps.